# How to use sqlserver jdbc jar in separate classloaders in the same JVM?

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, jdbc

I have a situation where I have a Maven Surefire test that uses the MS SQL JDBC driver.

And when complete, a follow-up `maven:exec` task runs at the end (in the same JVM) that also needs JDBC driver.

When I try to use it, the classloader is different than it was for the `maven:verify`. So the `maven:exec` task has an error complaining about SQL server driver cannot be loaded. It's not available in the given classloader.

Should we try to "unload" the MS sql server JDBC jar from the previous classloader, and reload it again in the correct classloader?

If so, how do I do that?

If not, is there some other way?

Note we know we can get this working with JVM process forking. And we do not want to resort to JVM process forking. We've done that previously and the complexity it adds is annoying. We gain a lot from sticking to the same JVM.

Here is my maven:exec configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>my-job</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.my.Job</mainClass>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <key>file.encoding</key>
                        <value>UTF-8</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You might try to configure some dummy 'maven:exec' early in the build cycle, so it forces the JDBC driver to be loaded before Surefire runs

Comment: I do believe `maven:exec` does always fork new process: "execute programs and Java programs in a separate process". How have you configured `maven:exec` goal? It has a plenty of options to configure classpath.

Comment: added the maven:exec configuration i'm using. it definitely does not fork a process at this point.

Comment: nothing was working so we went ahead and used a separate task in our build pipeline. it's PITA but it's worth it.